# How are Gnome shell extensions supposed to be managed?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, gnome-shell

I'm having trouble understanding the intended way of managing Gnome shell extensions.

I can't find any appropriate programs in the Dash for doing that. The only way I can actually manage extensions is via [extensions.gnome.org](http://extensions.gnome.org/).

It's impossible that this page is supposed to be the tool for managing extensions - it makes absolutely zero sense (it breaks UX, for one).

Please tell me that there is a plan for a native application aimed at managing these handy extensions.

Comment: What "breaks" user experience or not is highly subjective.

Comment: Well yes but I'm quite sure that the opinion that it does not break UX is the minority opinion.     
*Expected: open native application, select extension, install. Done
*Currently: open browser, install browser extension, navigate to webpage, install actual extension. Done.

Comment: When I changed my systems from `Microsoft Windows XP` to debian based `GNU/Linux Distributions` one of the most enlightening part of `user experience` was that I did not need to go to web pages, search for applications, download and install them but instead could search through the package list via `apt-get` and install the packages. Also I did not need to take much care about upgrades of individual applications since this was done with two `apt commands`. From my `highly subjective` user experience I have to say that it kind of feels `broken` when I have to manage Extensions this way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> It's impossible that this page is supposed to be the tool for managing
>   extensions - it makes absolutely zero sense

Whether it makes sense or not is also a matter of opinion. But yes, that page is the main tool, read Owen Taylor's [explanation.](http://lwn.net/Articles/460037/)
As to managing the extensions already installed on your system, you can enable/disable them via [gnome-tweak-tool](https://live.gnome.org/GnomeTweakTool) (or `dconf-editor` - GUI, or `gsettings` - CLI).

**edit:**
In reply to your comment:

> *I was talking about keeping the UX consistent. When I type "exten" into*
>   *the search bar, I should be able to get to some extension control point.*

What version of gnome-shell are you using ? On `gnome-3.8.2` that is the default behaviour, typing `exten` in the search bar brings up `gnome-tweak-tool` i.e. the "local control center" for extensions, see for yourself:

[image]