# How can I install GNOME shell extensions from extensions.gnome.org through Firefox on NixOS?

Tags: gnome3, firefox, gnome-shell, nixos

The website https://extensions.gnome.org [is supposed to be the main tool](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75980/161209) for installing and managing GNOME shell extensions. How do I enable it on NixOS 18.03?

When I accessed that website with Firefox on GNOME 3, I got the following information:

> To control GNOME Shell extensions using this site you must install GNOME Shell integration that consists of two parts: browser extension and native host messaging application.
>
> [Click here to install browser extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/#). See [wiki page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation) for native host connector installation instructions.

[image: Screenshot of error message: "To control GNOME Shell extensions using this site you must install GNOME Shell integration that consists of two parts: browser extension and native host messaging application. Click here to install browser extension. See wiki page for native host connector installation instructions."]

So I've added `pkgs.chrome-gnome-shell` and `pkgs.gnome3.gnome-shell-extensions` to `environment.systemPackages` in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`, rebuilt, rebooted and installed the "GNOME Shell integration" Firefox extension offered by https://extensions.gnome.org. With that, https://extensions.gnome.org displays the error message

> Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer [documentation](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation) for instructions about installing connector.

[image: Screenshot of error message "Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector."]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [longDescription](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/18.03/pkgs/desktops/gnome-3/extensions/chrome-gnome-shell/default.nix#L37) for [`chrome-gnome-shell`](https://nixos.org/nixos/packages.html#chrome-gnome-shell) says, you'll have to set a specific gnome3 and a specific firefox option. To do so, include the following in `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` and rebuild:

```
  nixpkgs.config.firefox.enableGnomeExtensions = true;
  services.gnome3.chrome-gnome-shell.enable = true;
```

(Unfortunately, these options [aren't](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#nixpkgs.config.firefox.enablegnomeextensions) [listed](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#services.gnome3.chrome-gnome-shell.enable) on https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html)

You don't have to explicitly list `chrome-gnome-shell` and `gnome3.gnome-shell-extensions` as system packages, as they will be pulled in as dependencies. The "GNOME Shell integration" Firefox extension will still have to be installed by the user through Firefox, though, as you did.

Comment: Thanks to [acowley on IRC](https://matrix.to/#/!AinLFXQRxTuqNpXyXk:matrix.org/$1523378179154161bTUUu:matrix.org) for making me aware of these options.

Comment: I tried this myself and it isn't working for me. Still getting the host connector missing error. 'tis perplexing. I've rebooted since the rebuild, I've double checked that the Firefox extension is installed.

Comment: There is currently an issue with where nixpkgs places the native-messaging-host json manifest: Firefox does not look in the current directory nixpkgs installs the manifest.

A workaround:

1. determine the location of the the manifest `org.gnome.chrome_gnome_shell.json`
2. place under `~/.mozilla/native-messaging-hosts/`